# How can I write a Python function that counts the number of times a letter occurs in a string?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key

I've got two problems with the following code

```
S = "acbcbba"

def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in result.keys():
                result[letter.lower()] += 1
            else:
                result[letter.lower()] = 1
            print(result)
    return(result)

count_letters(S)
```

Firstly, I can't figure out how to modify it so it only returns 1 dictionary instead of as many dictionaries as there letters in the string.

Secondly, I then need to be able to access each key to figure out if the value associated with it is odd and return the keys that have odd values associated with them?

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: What are you talking about? You already **are** returning only one dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't returning multiple dictionaries, it is *returning* 1 dictionary, and *printing* the others. Just remove your `print` statement.

Regarding querying for items which have an odd number of counts you can use a list comprehension of the dictionary's `items()` and filter out by their value (i.e. count) being odd.

```
>>> d = count_letters(S)
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
>>> [key for key, value in d.items() if value % 2 == 1]
['b']
```

If you want a list of the key value pairs then you can do something similar

```
>>> [(key, value) for key, value in d.items() if value % 2 ==1 ]
[('b', 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is there a way of doing a very similar thing but returning the key, value pair? I need to be able to return how to make each letter of the string occur an even number of times in this instance I need to return 1 subtract 1 value of b. or for deeded it needs to be 2, one letter of e and one letter d?

Answer (score 1):

All was about an indentation but here is a solution

```
S = "acbcbba"

def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in result.keys():
                result[letter.lower()] += 1
            else:
                result[letter.lower()] = 1
    print(result)
    return(result)

count_letters(S)
```

output

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

anyway there was no reason to return if there is `print` in the function or you could `return` result only and thereafter `print` it like the following

```
S = "acbcbba"

def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in result.keys():
                result[letter.lower()] += 1
            else:
                result[letter.lower()] = 1
    return(result)

print(count_letters(S))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in functions for that. For counting a specific character, just do `S.count('a')`. For getting a dictionary with all characters you could do something like that

```
S = "acbcbba"

my_dict = {k:S.count(k) for k in set(S)}
```